# <video> element with empty src-attribute creates console warning "Invalid URI. Load of media resource failed."

Tags: html

I have a video tag with an empty src-attribute. This is because i change the src based on what the user clicks. So i fill in the video-src after the page load. Now when i load the page i get the following warning in firefox:

```
Invalid URI. Load of media resource  failed.
```

The tag:

```
<video id="media-player-video" class="js-player" src=""></video>
```

Is it possible to not check the source attribute on page-load to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `preload="none"` to your video tag:

```html
<video id="media-player-video" class="js-player" src="" preload="none"></video>
```

Visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp) for a preload attribute documentation

Comment: Thx, but still the same warning